# Eclipse. Adding a file without duplicating it into the workspace

Tags: javascript, html, css, eclipse

I want to load the entire `www` folder from the wamp folder into the Eclipse project and work on it from here. I've created a `Static Web Project` and tried Importing the files from the `www` folder in there, but it just makes duplicates of those file. How can i open all the `www` files in Eclipse, so any change i make in the IDE it appears in the files in the `www` folder. I'm sure it's something simple, but it seems at this time of day, i'm really out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible if you try creating a Linked folder inside Eclipse.

Take a look at **[this](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-45.htm)**.

**Update**

Also, steps to do this (from **[here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t151684-how-to-simply-create-an-eclipse-project-and-add-some-existing-java-source-files.html)**) :

```
If you don't want to put your source code in the project, you can
"link" the source code to the project instead. In that case, you should
do the following:

1. Right-click the project, and choose Properties from the context menu.
2. Select "Java Build Path" from the left-hand side.
3. Click the "Source" tab along the top.
4. Click the "Link Source..." button.
5. Fill out the dialog box, and click the OK buttons.
```

Comment: Excellent. Just what I was looking for. I knew it would be a basic thing, but i couldn't find it. Accept in 8 min. Thanks again :)